# jQuery target link with specific href on click

Tags: jquery, onclick

This I should know but it has eluded me. I have the following HTML generated by AVADA shortcode for tabs:

```
<a href="#tab34830639">Customer Address</a>
```

I want to do something like below but I am stuck.

```
jQuery("a:href='#tab34830639'").click(function(){
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`attribute equals selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/),

```
jQuery("a[href='#tab34830639']").click(function(){
```

This `"a:href='#tab34830639'"` is an invalid jquery selector.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a[href="#tab34830639"]').click(function() {
```

Available attributes:

```
= is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= it starts with
$= it ends with
*= it contains
~= it contains word
|= it starts with prefix (i.e., |= "prefix" matches "prefix-...")
```

[Attributes Documentation Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

And here is a working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GLLcY/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [`attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this

```
jQuery("a[href='#tab34830639']").click(function(){
```

Note : Attribute equal selector - Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.